# admob wp7 sdk dont work, alternative ad networks?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i use the admob wp7 sdk for displaying adds in my apps, but i dont see any, it looke like:

```
<google:BannerAd
    xmlns:google="clr-namespace:Google.AdMob.Ads.WindowsPhone7.WPF;assembly=Google.AdMob.Ads.WindowsPhone7"
    AdUnitID="MY_AD_UNIT_ID">
```

of course i insert my adUnitID, when i start my app i dont get anything to see, also when i enable test mode i cant see anything, what could be worng? on the homepage i see that i got requests because it counts up, but nothing to see.

**other question:**

are there any other add providers instead of smaato and adDuplex which provide a WP7 sdk?

Answer (score 3):

As of today the Microsoft Ad SDK for WP7 can now be used in all territories where the marketplace is available.

Alternatively you could consider [AdDuplex](http://www.adduplex.com/)

Comment: @roman I believe that Marketplace was only available in those countries when I originally answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the documentation and contacting admob support. Its a third party control so you would be lucky to find someone on here who can offer advice.