# AdMob in Windows phone - Ad Not Available (NoFill)

Tags: windows-phone-7, admob, ads

I've downloaded latest SDK 4.0.4 and tried to use code from example, but always get

**Error: Ad Not Available (NoFill)**

```
<google:BannerAd xmlns:google="clr-namespace:Google.AdMob.Ads.WindowsPhone7.WPF;assembly=Google.AdMob.Ads.WindowsPhone7"
        AdUnitID="a150bdc5e445270">
        <google:BannerAd.TestDeviceIDs>
            <sys:String>3iys+Gjads@3#%IMJvcYsZd+6UHij58=</sys:String>
        </google:BannerAd.TestDeviceIDs>
</google:BannerAd>
```

Also i checked that WP7 app is added in AdMob account and it is active.
BTW i see 10 requests from yesterday (it is strange, because i am sure that i tried to launch it at least 20 times). In documentation i found that in WP apps it can be time lag < 2 mins. I waited more 10 minutes, it also did not helper me.

Test mode is enabled in AdMob account. I tried implement both without TestDeviceID and with it. 
Also i found at least 2 similar questions on SO, but they are still not resolved:

[admob wp7 sdk dont work, alternative ad networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436458/admob-wp7-sdk-dont-work-alternative-ad-networks)

[Admob not showing in New Windows Phone 7 Silverlight Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552464/admob-not-showing-in-new-windows-phone-7-silverlight-project)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and may switch out of admob if the problem continues.

For now base on their FAQ

Why do I keep getting "AdFailed - Ad not available" on Windows Phone 7?

Windows Phone 7 is new to the AdMob market, so in the short term you may see some low fill rates until advertisers add this platform to their targeting. Using test mode during development should eliminate inventory as a variable in your SDK integration testing. Please see the discussion of this feature here.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/#wp7whynoads